# Log API failures in Jmeter run using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

We are using Jenkins pipeline to run jmeter tests for testing one of our application API. EVeryting is working ok but there are cases where the Application returns an error. We would like to log the request payload for such failures and also the timestamp so that we can investigate in the application about corresponding failures.

Is there a way, I can instruct jmeter to log the Request Data for cases which result in failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is adding a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to your test plan.

The configuration to save the timestamp and payload would look like:

[image]

Once the test finishes you will be able to observe requests details (if any) using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri - that helped and it worked. I am wondering if it is possible to include these in the jtl report as well.

Comment: The linked article contains the instructions, just in case it will change in the future: 1. You need to switch the report format to XML. 2. You need to instruct JMeter to save request data and headers. So you will need to add next 3 lines to *user.properties* file: `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml`, `jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true`, `jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true`. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)